# C++ how to compile __thiscall in MS VC++ 6.0

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, calling-convention

Let's say I have this code which is generated using HexRays.. but it seems the `__thiscall` cannot be used in VC++ 6.0.

`nonstandard extension used : '__thiscall' keyword reserved for future use`

How do I get around this in VC++ 6.0?

```
long v4 = 0x004AC370;
#define _DWORD long
(*(void (__thiscall **)(int, int))(*(_DWORD *)v4 + 76))(v4, 8);
```

How do I call the above in MS VC++ 6.0.

I know __thiscall is used for class members, but I have the pointer and would like to avoid any class crafting.

Thanks.

Comment: For readers lacking context, here's the full question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980306/how-to-call-this-assembly-function-in-inlined-asm-in-c-dll-injection

Comment: Well Greg I figured.. if i cannot call the whole function in that last question.. So why not call the inner-functions as they are semi c++ code, then the whole function.. to see what will happen.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer-to-member-function (you'd need to define a class) is the only way in C++ to supply the implicit `this` parameter.  Other than that, you can use inline assembly.

Comment: how can I do this in inline assembly? and is `this` always static?